# In Illustrator, how do I cut off a protruding end of a path through a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

How do I cut or trim off the protruding line drawn using a pen tool so that it confirms the shape of the rectangle?

[image]

Comment: Look up how to use [clipping masks](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)

Comment: You cannot use the pen tool to cut a diagonal stroke to fit a 90º direction. Use the answer of @Dodie Eslava or the Billy Kerr comment.

Answer (score 1):

Select the two layer then ude divide tool.
Make sure the given line is not stroke. If the line is stronke expand it first.
[image]

Select the unwanted path then delete.

[image]

Comment: That's not the best way, and it's not exactly what's being asked... There are other ways to do it without having to transform the path in a shape.

Comment: Why dont you give your own answer then. There are many options to do it and i just give what i have. Give yours also if you want.  You're good only in commenting and yet you offer no solution.

Comment: Chill out, I'm not personally attacking you here. There is one other answer (which I upvoted) and a comment with a different solution, I don't need to add another one just to say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

- Select both the rectangle and inner shape
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Hold down the **<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>** key
- **Click-drag** across the part of the line you want to remove.